# jsoup to sanitize HTML working fine when entering new data but not on edit

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using jsoup to clean html code entered by users (typically: the user forgot to close a  tag). It is working very well for new entries but doesn't do anything when editing a previous entry (already cleaned by jsoup). Here is the code:

```
public void on_newMyData(Dictionary d, Attributes a, Transaction t) throws LogicException {
  sanitizeHTMLInput(d,a,t);
}
public void on_editMyData(Dictionary d, Attributes a, Transaction t) throws LogicException {
  sanitizeHTMLInput(d,a,t);
}
private void sanitizeHTMLInput(Dictionary d, Attributes a, Transaction t) throws LogicException {
  try {
    Object unsafe = a.getAttribute("answer");
    String safe = Jsoup.clean(String.valueOf(unsafe), Whitelist.relaxed());
    d.put("answer",safe);       
  } catch (AttributeNotFoundException e) {
    //if the answer is empty, no sanitizing is needed
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a limitation that I didn't find?

Comment: What version of jsoup do you use?

Comment: I'm using version 1.6.1

Comment: Is the `sanitizeHTMLInput` method executed after the user made its edit? You cen test if jsoup detects the "unsafe" html with [isValid()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#isValid(java.lang.String,%20org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist)) Method. If possible check if the problem is in current version (1.7.2) too.